# guzzlehttp error

Tags: wordpress

CiviCRM and Xero for Woocommerce plugins on Wordpress (latest versions of all) are not playing nicely. When trying to load the latter plugin, this exception is generated:

```
2022-01-19T00:22:04+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\choose_handler() in /var/www/ap/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/HandlerStack.php:42
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/ap/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(65): GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack::create()
#1 /var/www/ap/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(132): GuzzleHttp\Client->__construct()
#2 /var/www/ap/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/GenericProvider.php(99): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->__construct()
#3 /var/www/ap/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-xero/includes/class-wc-xr-oauth20-storage.php(208): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider->__construct()
#4 /var/www/ap/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-xero/includes/class-wc-xr-oauth20-storage.php(46): WC_XR_OAuth20_Storage_Class::create_provider()
#5 /var/www/ap/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-xero/includes/class-wc-xr-oauth20. in /var/www/ap/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/HandlerStack.php on line 42
```

Is there any way for a relative non-techie to work out which plugin is causing the issue? Woocommerce Xero crashes when trying to oauth with Xero... looks like maybe both civi & this plugin are trying to oauth, but as it's a totally new out of the box civi installation I can't work out why civi would be doing that

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I stumbled on this error because the site had an old version of the plugin "google-listings-and-ads" (I haven't yet tested with the latest version).

I found it by running:

```
grep -r Guzzle wp-content/plugins/  | cut -f 3 -d '/' | sort | uniq
```

and then deactivating the plugins one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand now that no one tool is any more 'at fault' than the other - I have found another plugin for Xero/Woo which claims to have resolved this, so I'll investigate that instead.